# Rails server does not start -> Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I created a new rails app in folder 'issues' and when I wanted to 'ruby s' I got an error.  Any help will be much appreciated

```
[thiago@netbox issues]$ rails s
/home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/thiago/Documents/wdi/rails_practice/issues/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I added 'therubyracer' gem into my Gemfile and then '$ bundle install'  Works!

```
Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'therubyracer' # added
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Gemfile?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same error both for Windows and Ubuntu when I started working on Rails in January.   The error is pretty straightforward. You need a JavaScript runtime environment for the server to start.

There are a number of solutions to this. The one I use on Ubuntu is to install NodeJS.

On Ubuntu you'd run something like the following to install NodeJS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install nodejs
```

Those are the commands I use to do it as it will install the latest stable version of NodeJS, but you can just run `sudo apt-get -y install nodejs` and be fine.

On Windows, the answer I used, and there may be others, was to edit your Gemfile to install therubyracer. I work on Rails 4.0 RC1 apps right now and they all have `gem 'therubyracer', platform: :ruby` already in the Gemfile just commented out.

You can just go add `gem 'therubyracer'` in your Gemfile if you're running on Windows and that will get you running I'd bet. Then run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 8):

A JavaScript runtime cannot be find. I would suppose that you don't have one in your Gemfile.
Try editing your Gemfile and add

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

And then run

```
$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a javascript Interpreter:

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem "libv8", ">= 3.11.8"
gem "therubyracer", ">= 0.11.0", :group => :assets, :platform => :ruby, :require => "v8"
```

Also you can check other options like Node.js for production, but for development it will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should open `/home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb` and go to line `51`. See what resource `autodetect` is looking for. This seems to be missing.

You probably have a dependency that didn't load. Best strategy is to create a fresh ruby gem environment with `rbenv` or `rvm`, then bundle again. Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

- **Possible Problem:** My Rails-server did not start on Windows 7, because ExecJS was unable to detect a Javascript Runtime, even though, I had NodeJS installed.
- **Reason on my machine:** The NodeJS-directory was part of the environment, but surrounded by quotations (eg. `[...];"C:\Program Files\nodejs\";[...]`). This lead to `where` and ExecJS being unable to understand the path-entry and, eventually, not finding the node.js executable.
- **Solution:** see below...

---

#### To get my Rails-server to start on Windows (7 64bit), I

- **installed NodeJS** to a directory that does **NOT** include spaces (eg. in `C:\development\nodejs\`)
  ... because where (Windows version of which) was not able to find executables in the PATH if the respective entry was surrounded by quotation marks
- made sure that `where node` returned the node-executable (eg. `C:\development\nodejs\node.exe`) I just installed
  (if where can't find NodeJS, execJS will probably not find it either)
  if `where node` returns an error, check your PATH-variable, you may want to move the entry for NodeJS to the front and NOT use quotation marks
- excluded therubyracer from the Gemfile by changing the respective line to
  `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby`
  (as said before) this will lead to therubyracer being installed in Linux/production environment, but not on local Windows environment
- deleted the Gemfile.lock and called `bundle install` in order to have a clean installation of the gemfiles
- started Rails with `rails server`

Answer (score 0):

It won't allow you to start the server inside any directory. Just go to the root directory and type

```
rails server
```

or

```
rails s
```