# Ruby on Rails for Windows: how to get started without getting a different error every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-8.1, execjs

I'm on Windows 8.1 and have been trying to get Rails to work on my computer for quite some time now.  I followed the guides to install Ruby and Rails and everything correctly, but whenever I try to execute any kind of Rails command through PowerShell, I get an error with one of the gems.  I can't run the server command, can't generate, can't run console.  Here is the most recent error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in 'autodetect': Could not find a Javascript runtime.  See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.  (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)}
```

Other times I get errors with native gems follow guides to resolve those, but nothing ends up working.

How do I get Rails to do anything on my Windows machine?  Should I just get a Linux vm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a vm, I've used virtualbox in the past with ubuntu for rails development.

It's not impossible to get things to work in windows, but you'll probably thank yourself later if you move to the vm. 
For the specific error you mention see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846088/rails-server-does-not-start-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime) which suggests adding therubyracer gem.

Comment: I thought I had downloaded therubyracer gem already, but I'll follow your suggestion and go ahead with a vm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a different error every time then providing an answer with the steps to get it running would be very hard so I'll stick to a general answer.

With persistence (which, don't get me wrong, you've already shown) you can get rails up and running on a Windows machine. You will spend longer getting native gems to work properly and you will have to search harder, and longer, for solutions to some problems.

I have run rails on both windows (admittedly a few years ago now) and on linux and I have found the latter to be much easier to develop on.

So, it's a trade off between the pain of running rails under windows and the pain of running some of your dev environment on a virtual machine. Only you can decide which is the least painful for you.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how I can resolve this 'execjs' gem not being able to find a runtime?  I already have NodeJS and therubyracer installed, which is what the provided link led to.  I might follow your advice and just get a virtual machine because I am getting a little frustrated at this point

Comment: There are definitely answers out there. If I get into solving your exact problems though we could be in an unending dialogue of moving from one problem to the next. My advice would be to ask specific questions for the specific problems if you can't find the answers. I will of course look at those specific questions on SO.